# How to express one to one relationship in pure relational model?

Tags: database, relational-database

For example, entity A(primary key:a) and B(primary key:b) participate in the relationship C. This is a one-to-one relationship. I think C(a, b) is not enough, right? So how to express it using pure relational model?

Answer (score 0):

If it's one to one,  you don't need a third table to express the relationship.  you can add a field to B that would refer to A (foreign key) , or the other way around.  I would normally have a column in the sub entity pointing to the parent entity.

In fact,  if B can be considered a sub entity of A, since it's a one to one relationship,  some models would include the fields of B in the same table as a,  and then you won't need an identifier column for B. This way you'll need only a single table.

C is only necessary if it it's a many to many relationship.